# What happens if a token symbol has four letters?

Tags: exchanges

What happens if a token symbol has four letters? Do exchanges display it as only first three letters, don't display it at all or? If they display only first three letters I would have a problem with duplicates... Should I be ok with 4 letter symbol on exchanges? If somebody can explain. Thanks. (and yes I checked similar threads but found not what I was looking for)

Comment: Also do sites like coin market cup cut it down to first three letters? Or if anyone knows if there are any other possible problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens if a token symbol has four letters?

It should be fine. Running a script I wrote a while back, which pulls token data from CoinMarketCap and counts the occurrences of different lengths, gives:

```
Asset symbols of length 1: 3
Asset symbols of length 2: 39
Asset symbols of length 3: 874
Asset symbols of length 4: 391
Asset symbols of length 5: 153
Asset symbols of length 6: 18
Asset symbols of length 7: 4
Asset symbols of length 8: 3
Asset symbols of length 9: 1
```

The caveat is that this isn't just ERC-20 symbols - it symbols for all currencies, including ERC-20 tokens. But the same argument holds regardless.

> Do exchanges display it as only first three letters, don't display it at all or?

CoinMarketCap shows symbols of any length. However, it will likely depend on the exchange. Given there are so many that aren't 3 letters long, I'd guess that most exchanges would allow it.

> If they display only first three letters I would have a problem with duplicates...

There's no rule prohibiting duplicate token symbols. (Just search in EtherScan's token page and you'll see there are lots of either old/superceded or fake token contracts which share the same symbol.)