# How do companies register ICO ticker

Tags: ico

For example Did bitcoin have to register "BTC" as their ticker if thats what they call it,the three letter symbol

Answer (score 2):

For ERC-20 tokens, there's an optional `symbol` variable that can be defined in the token's contract.

The act of defining this is perhaps orthogonal to it being registered on, and displayed by, any particular site or exchange, but I imagine many sites will read these values directly from the token's contract.

Note that these aren't limited to 3 letters, as per "[Is there length limits on Token Symbols?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25619/is-there-length-limits-on-token-symbols)".

(Also see: [What happens if a token symbol has four letters?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37322/what-happens-if-a-token-symbol-has-four-letters))

Running the counting script from one of those previous answers again, for fun, gives:

```
Asset symbols of length 1: 3
Asset symbols of length 2: 41
Asset symbols of length 3: 924
Asset symbols of length 4: 387
Asset symbols of length 5: 151
Asset symbols of length 6: 17
Asset symbols of length 7: 4
Asset symbols of length 8: 3
Asset symbols of length 9: 1
```

So most symbols are 3 characters long. This is all assets, not just ERC-20 tokens. Data is from CoinMarketCap.

Answer (score 2):

First, they do not "register" a ticker. There is no copyright on the ticker "BTC" or "ETH".

This has become standard because it is called like this in Satoshi and Vitalik original whitepaper.

When creating an ERC20 token with Ethereum for example, it is good practice to specify a name and a symbol for your token.

Taken from the official token documentation:

`contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;`

As it is in your on interest to avoid confusion for your future investors,  you need to take a name that will not be confused with another existing coin, but nothing stop me from calling my new token "BTC".

Most of the ICO creators aim to deliver their coin on exchanges platform. Those are centralized, hence you need to register or ask them specifically to label your coin as "XXX". Exchanges will not accept a new coin that has the same name as an other,  as it would be too confusing for their user and for them.

So no, you have no limitation when naming your coin, but it is in everyone best interest to give it an unused or distinctive name.

Comment: Shaun Ferns, please, mark this answer as correct if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum is a decentralized network. There is no centralized registration authority for ticker symbols.

Some places you can register your ticker

- Parity wallet
- EtherScan
- MetaMask
- MyEtherWallet
- Various exchanges

Comment: You can not register anything in Blockchain. Ticker (symbol) is optional parameter, nothing more. The only thing, which distinguish particular token is ADDRESS.